# Silverlight 5 NotificationWindow captures mainwindow mouse

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob, silverlight-5.0

I'm finding that if you use the NotificationWindow with Silverlight 5 runtime in an out of browser app, while the notificationwindow is visible it captures any mouse input in the top left corner of the application's main window.

This can be easily demonstrated for example the sample here : http://forums.silverlight.net/t/212852.aspx/1

You simply add a button so it sits at the top left of the screen. It is not possible to click the button while the NotificationWindow is visible. This does NOT happen on SL4 runtime, but does happen on each of the SL5 machines I have tested.

The area that gets captured corresponds to the size of the NotificationWindow, as if the notification window was located at the top left of the MainWindow. If your NotificationWindow content has any controls, you can even click those controls by clicking in the corresponding location on the main window!

I've hit this problem on a SL4 application where users with Silverlight 5 runtime can no longer use the buttons on the top left of the main window.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Danny

Comment: It would be great if someone could confirm they get the same result as me.

I believe this is a Silverlight 5 bug that will affect any app using the NotificationWindow.

Comment: (sorry for my bad english) I just found out this bug on my own OOB app (SL5). On my case I used the `IsHitTestVisible = false` (on the NotificationWindow Content) workaround since I do not need the click event on the Notification.

Comment: I reproduced this. It does indeed appear to be a bug: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightbugs/thread/69532987-ff08-4592-9b9a-5840514bf40c/. Also; tnx to Leo for the workaround.